# the addValueEventlistener not compiled , the compiler go to next step directly

Tags: android, firebase

```
switch (v.getId()) {
    case R.id.signUpBtn:

        database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
        myRef = database.child("users");
        users = new Users();
        getValue();
        myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
            @Override
            public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {
                myRef.setValue(users);
                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Data inserted....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            }

            @Override
            public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

            }
        });
        // Call checkValidation method
        checkValidation();


        break;
```

I tried to use a break point to no avail, the compiler goes to `checkValidation()` directly, skipping the `addValueEventlistener`!?

Answer (score 0):

It's true and that is because of the `onDataChange` is asynchronous which means that the compiler will move to another task and won't wait the `onDataChange` to retrieve it's data.

Example if you add a `Log`:

```
switch (v.getId()) {
case R.id.signUpBtn:
    database = FirebaseDatabase.getInstance().getReference();
    myRef = database.child("users");
    users = new Users();
    getValue();
    Log.d(TAG,"Before add value listener");

    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

            myRef.setValue(users);
            Log.d(TAG,"inside retrieving data");
            Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Data inserted....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

        }
    });
    // Call checkValidation method
    Log.d(TAG, "outside retrieving data");
    checkValidation();

    break;
```

This will print the log in the following order:

> Before add Value Listener
>
> outside retrieve data
>
> inside retrieving data

To solve this add `checkValidation();` inside the `onDataChange`, example:

```
    myRef.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
    @Override
    public void onDataChange(@NonNull DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        myRef.setValue(users);
        Log.d(TAG,"inside retrieving data");
        Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Data inserted....", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();  
        checkValidation();
    }

    @Override
    public void onCancelled(@NonNull DatabaseError databaseError) {

    }
});
```

Comment: yes it's asynchronous , but it has not been executed at all !!
my users object has not been added to database nor (Log) nor Toast message appeared.

Comment: did you add the method inside ondatachange

Comment: do you mean a screenshot of firebase page ,or what ?

Comment: yes a screenshot of your database, since it is not executing the ondatachange then your location might be wrong `ref()`